# Access to the path 'C:\Users\username\Documents\test.txt' is denied

Tags: c#, .net, io, uwp, file-access

I am working on a visual studio UWP project and I created a static class to create/open a file and write json data to the file.

I am encountering the access denied error and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

I am running Windows 10 Pro. Visual Studio 2015. .NETCore 5.2.2.

Here is the code:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\test.txt") )
{
    using(JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, brand);
    }
}
```

Things I've tried so far:

- Running VS in Admin Mode.
- Running the app in debug or without debugging.
- Using different directories
- I tried creating the "test.txt" file with full read/write permission to everyone.

Help is appreciated!
Zach

Comment: What sort of different directories? Even something you should *definitely* have access to, such as your desktop?

Comment: Yep. Tried desktop too.

Comment: UWP sandboxes file acces, [you can't just open any file on the drive like that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Yeah writing to the root C: drive is locked down to hell in windows. Create a temp folder like "C:\temp" and try writing there.

Comment: Thank you Scott Chamberlain. Your answer gave me the necessary information to proceed. If you convert your comment to an answer I will mark it as the answer.